# Cross-reference random elements

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to cross-reference custom items in my document the same way I would do for figures, tables etc... For example I would like to add something like `\label{custom_item: label}` and then use something like `\ref{custom_item: label}` to produce "Item 1", "Item 2" etc.. How can I do it? Obviously the label "Item" would be written every time and not produced by LaTeX, the same way you have to write "Figure" when referencing figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a counter that you increase with `\refstepcounter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{myitem}
\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{myitem}\label{myitem-a}
\refstepcounter{myitem}\label{myitem-b}

Item~\ref{myitem-a}, Item~\ref{myitem-b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works great.

Comment: @Adam With a bit more work with cleverref or hyperref, you can also get the `Item~` part to appear.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you.